While generating avro-schema using code, default date is coming as 0
I have below code to generate the avro-schema from class models. The default value of date is giving as 1970,1,1
from datetime import date
from dataclasses_avroschema.pydantic import AvroBaseModel
from pydantic import Field


class EffectiveUpToDateAtDest(AvroBaseModel):
    name: str = Field(default="udcEffectiveUpToDateAtDest")
    value: date = Field(
        metadata={
            "doc": "This is the date when this sourcing is no longer in effect, based on last arrival at destination"
        },
        default=date(1970, 1, 1),
    )

print(EffectiveUpToDateAtDest.avro_schema())

But, in output schema, default value of date is coming as 0.
GithubDocs: https://github.com/marcosschroh/dataclasses-avroschema
https://marcosschroh.github.io/dataclasses-avroschema/
Current Output
{"type": "record", "name": "EffectiveUpToDateAtDest", "fields": [{"name": "name", "type": "string", "default": "udcEffectiveUpToDateAtDest"}, {"doc": "This is the date when this sourcing is no longer in effect, based on last arrival at destination", "name": "value", "type": {"type": "int", "logicalType": "date"}, "default": 0}]}

Expectation: default value of date should come as the same which I've provided in the Class Models i.e. 1970-01-01 (i.e. field value)

I went through the documentation. As we have provided the 1970-01-01 date, (which is a starting point) - So it;s coming as 0
If we gave 1971-01-01 (i.e. whole 365 days) then value will come as 365
https://marcosschroh.github.io/dataclasses-avroschema/fields_specification/
Date: The date logical type represents a date within the calendar, with no reference to a particular time zone or time of day. A date logical type annotates an Avro int, where the int stores the number of days from the unix epoch, 1 January 1970 (ISO calendar).
